# How to make a simple voice recorder in pcm format?

Tags: delphi, audio, pcm, wave

i created a simple voice recording using wav format. my problem is i wanted it to save as PCM format using Tbass components form http://www.un4seen.com. My compiler is delphi. or convertion from mp3/wav to pcm.

Answer (score 2):

I use the free New Audio Components to tasks like that, this component set is really nice and easy to use.

Check the demos, there is a voice recorder demo.

http://symmetrica.net/newac/

Comment: You saved my day today. There is almost no resource for high quality audio recording and these components are providing almost noiseless recording.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Peter Morris' [Converting WAV to MP3 and back](http://www.howtodothings.com/computers/a1383-converting-wav-to-mp3-and-back.html) could help.
He explains a lot about ACM and how to use it with Delphi (with msacm.pas).